# Custom Id in Grails Domain Classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there any way I can use the property defined in the belongsTo Field as primary key.

For example:

```
Class A {

   static belongsTo = [b: B]

   static mappings = {
       id generator: 'assigned', name: 'b'
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand this, this means the relationship is one to one, and you want the b_id column to be the unique identifier?

Comment: You would have to provide the case why you would want to do this. Seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: Yes Bill, you got it right. And @JamesKleeh, I do want because I don't want every time to see if the b_id already exists in the table, by sending query A.findByB(). Now I think you got my point.